# Neo4j Cypher - Conditional writes on matches

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

I have a database with users `(u:User {id: 1})`, user statuses `(us:UserStatus {status: 'pending'})`, and the relationships between them `(u)-[hs:HAS_STATUS {from: 1541030400, to: 4102444800}]->(us)`.

Where user statuses can be `"pending"`, `"active"` or `"suspended"`.
And `2100-01-01` is some date in the future meaning the user still has this status.

I'm trying to run a query that updates the status of the user by creating a new relationship with the new status and archives the old relationship by setting the `to` property to the current date.

This is what I've tried:

```
MERGE (u:User { id: 1 })
WITH u
MATCH (u)-[hs1:HAS_STATUS]->(us1:UserStatus)
WHERE us1.status <> 'active' AND hs1.to > 1544400000
SET hs1.to = 1544400000
MERGE (us2:UserStatus {status: 'active'})
MERGE (u)-[hs2:HAS_STATUS {from: 1544400000, to: 4102444800}]->(us2)
```

If the user already has a status that satisfies the `WHERE` clause then it is archived and the new status relationship is created. However if the user doesn't already have a status the `SET` clause is skipped (as intended) however the two `MERGE` lines are skipped also. How can I ensure that they are executed regardless of the merge?

**Edit:**
Original query had some typos.

Comment: Your query also seems to have typos (`hs` should probably be `hs1`). Can you edit your question to show your *actual query*?

Comment: Thanks this fixed part of the problem. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answers your updated question]

A `MATCH` (without the `OPTIONAL` qualifier) will abort the rest of the query if the match fails.

This query shows one way to match a pattern and optionally perform a write operation if the match succeeds, without aborting the rest of the query if the match fails:

```
MERGE (u:User { id: 1 })
FOREACH(hs IN
  [(u)-[hs1:HAS_STATUS]->(us1:UserStatus)
        WHERE us1.status <> 'active' AND hs1.to > 1544400000 | hs1] |
  SET hs.to = 1544400000)
MERGE (us2:UserStatus {status: 'active'})
MERGE (u)-[hs2:HAS_STATUS {from: 1544400000, to: 4102444800}]->(us2);
```

This query uses a [FOREACH](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/foreach/) clause to iterate through a list (of size 0 or 1, in this case) of matching `hs1` values, setting the `to` value of each one to `1544400000`. The list is generated by a [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension). Even if the list is empty, the rest of the query still executes.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Previous answer segment removed as you said the "dates" you're using in your query are actually a stand-in for epoch seconds.

If no rows are changed, then one of two things is happening.

1. Your MATCH (with associated WHERE) failed to find any matching pattern. You should try to just run that MATCH and WHERE to see if it returns any rows.
2. The relationship you're trying to MERGE in already exists. You might want to try to match to that relationship (with those properties) between those two nodes and see if it already exists.

Comment: Yes sorry you are right. I’m actually using epoch seconds for the dates, ‘2018-12-10’ was just for readability

Comment: That's a confusing thing...it's usually better off to provide the actual query to avoid confusion like this. Answer edited.